# "The operation could not be completed" error when users try to connect to TFS

Tags: tfs

I have a problem in my company where suddenly 2 users were having problems with connecting to TFS. They both get an error message saying

> The operation could not be completed

and then nothing more.

This happens on both Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 every time the user performs a TFS action, e.g. at checkin or viewing a Work Item

Both users did restart their computers with no luck. They both claim not having installed any 3rd party tools or done any update on the machine.

Do you guys have any idea why these errors are occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use on a client machines Power Tools. May be some politics are enabled on a server.
Or, IIS can reload tfs web services.

Comment: This problem seemed to be solved for the users, didn't really figure this out but both users reinstalled the Power Tools so that might be the issue. I've also had multiple users having check-in problems related to power tools.